# IErrorHandler implementation not handling exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ierrorhandler

I have a duplex WCF service which I am attempting to create a global exception handler for.

I have created a behaviour extension for an IErrorHandler implementation as per [this blog post](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler.aspx)

If I put a breakpoint on the ApplyDispatchBehavior method I can see my handler getting added to the channel dispatchers ErrorHandlers' property, but if I subsequently throw exceptions neither the HandleError or ProvideFault methods are called.

My error handler looks like this:

```
internal class ControlFrameworkErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ControlFrameworkWcfService));


    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        Logger.Fatal("An unhandled exception occurred:");
        Logger.Fatal(error.Message);
        Logger.Fatal(error.StackTrace);
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new ControlFrameworkErrorHandler();

        foreach (var channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My behavior implementation looks like this:

```
internal class ControlFrameworkErrorHandlerElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(ControlFrameworkErrorHandler);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new ControlFrameworkErrorHandler();
    }
}
```

And my App.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
          <service name="ControlFrameworkService.ControlFrameworkWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="ControlFrameworkServiceBehavior">
           <host>
             <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/ControlFrameworkService/service" />
             </baseAddresses>
           </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IControlFrameworkDuplex" contract="ControlFrameworkService.IControlFrameworkDuplex" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IControlFrameworkDuplex" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" sendTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="8388608" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:808/myClient/">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="8388608" maxBytesPerRead="8388608" maxNameTableCharCount="8388608" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ControlFrameworkErrorHandler" type="ControlFrameworkService.ControlFrameworkErrorHandlerElement, ControlFrameworkService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ControlFrameworkServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <ControlFrameworkErrorHandler />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true">
      </trace>
      <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"      propagateActivity="true">
          <listeners>
            <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="WcfDetailTrace.svclog" />
          </listeners>
        </source>
      </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can probably change `channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);` to `channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(this);` from the looks of it, since your behavior element has already created an instance of the error handler and the code adding it to the channeldispatchers is running inside the error handler.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the code in `HandleError` method to the `ProvideFault` method. For some reason, even though documentation says that `HandleError` should be used, that doesn't seem to be the case. I had the same issue as you and I solved it by using the `ProvideFault` method.

I have read a few other people suggesting the same thing as well out on the Interwebs.

If someone else has a better idea, I am all ears.